.NET OpenTelemetry Distributed Tracing
I want to use the OpenTelemetry Protocol (OTLP) for distributed tracing using Azure Functions that communicate with each other via Kafka messages.
First I did Dependency Injection (DI) with OpenTelemetry.Trace.Tracer? tracer in each class but I read this is bad practise so I changed to a singleton class with ActivitySource from System.Diagnostics for all Azure Function with same application name DistributedTracing:
public static class Tracing
{
    public static string ApplicationName = "DistributedTracing";
    public static readonly ActivitySource Source = new(ApplicationName);
}

Now I start a parent trace with
using var parentTrace = Tracing.Source.StartActivity("Trace");
var parentTraceId = parentTrace?.Activity?.TraceId.ToString();

in the first Azure Function of the workflow. The result of the first Azure Function is a Kafka message. This Kafka message consists of data for the workflow as well as the parentTraceId of the parentTrace defined above. The first Azure Function usually exits before the second Azure Function starts processing the message.
However I cannot achieve distributed tracing. In the next Azure Function I create a new Trace and set the Id from the parentTrace from the Kafka message like this:
using var distributedChildTrace = Tracing.Source.StartActivity("OCR Trace");
distributedChildTrace.SetParentId(kafkaMessage.ParentTraceId);

But while Trace does show up, thedistributed child trace OCR Trace is not a child, but its own root trace.
What am I doing wrong here?
Is it possible the traceparent is rejected because the trace already finished before the traceparent will be picked set in the follow up workflow?


